What are the risks of running an IHost instance and WebApplication instance within a single .NET process?
In an attempt to launch both a function app and a gRPC server in the same process, I am spawning two builders, one in a non-blocking fashion in the background (fn_host.RunAsync()) for the FunctionsWebApplication, and the other in a blocking fashion in the foreground (grpcHost.Run()) for WebApplication (that hosts the gRPC server) to keep the parent process running.
I am aware that the background sub process runs the risk of failing silently, but this can be handled by external health checks such as liveness probes in production.
While this approach works, I would like to know if there are any side effects (especially those specific to .NET) of running a FunctionsWebApplication instance and WebApplication instance within the same .NET process.
IHost fn_host = new HostBuilder()
     .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication(builder =>
     {
         builder.Services.Configure<JsonSerializerOptions>(options =>
         {
             options.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
         });
     })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((
        hostContext,
        configuration) =>
    {
        configuration.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, false)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", true, false)
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true, false)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {

        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();


        IConfiguration configuration = hostContext.Configuration;

        services
            .AddBindings()
            .AddConfig(configuration)
            .AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));
    })
    .Build();

fn_host.RunAsync();



var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddGrpc();

builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    options.ListenLocalhost(5000, o => o.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2);
});

var grpcHost = builder.Build();

grpcHost.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();

grpcHost.Run();


Are they interdependent?

No they are not, but they will share some business logic classes (not the same instances).

No, there is no downsides. Just synchronize their lifetimes and you are good to go. To synchronize them you could share same cancellationToken for both services, and when either of them fails - you cancel entire application with same error. Kind of how unhandled exceptions works at appdomain level.
Why Im so sure about this:

We executed same strategy long time ago. It works perfectly and there were no conflicts/gotchas in production up to this point in time, except obvious shared configurations like ServicePointManager/ServiceLocator/etc. So, just avoid those pesky static classes/configurations where possible. For configuration you can use different prefixes in environment variables, for service locator you can register both dependencies, before build.
We usually start plethora of those services in Integration tests, which also works perfectly.

